# Swift Combine, Avoid nested subscribers on optionals

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, combine

I have an AccountService class that holds a User object. The user object gets set async from a network request.
In my UI I'm displaying the user and want to keep changes up to date. I'm using the Swift Combine  Framework to do this.

## Question: Is there a way to avoid nested subscribers on an object?

I wrote some test code to illustrate this:

```swift
import UIKit
import Combine

class User: ObservableObject, CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    @Published
    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    var debugDescription: String {
        return self.name
    }
}

class AccountService {

    @Published
    var user: User? = nil

    var userCancel: AnyCancellable?
    var userContentCancel: AnyCancellable?
    init() {
        self.userCancel = self.$user.sink { (user) in
            print("Set user: \(String(describing: user))")

            guard let user = user else { return }
            self.userContentCancel = user.$name.sink { _ in
                print("new name: \(String(describing: self.user))")
            }
        }
    }

    func setUseru(user: User) {
        self.user = user
    }

    func changeUserName(name: String) {
        self.user?.name = name
    }
}

let x = AccountService()
x.setUseru(user: User(name: "Philipp"))
x.changeUserName(name: "Tom")
x.setUseru(user: User(name: "Anna"))
```

*Run in Playgroud Xcode Version 11.4.1, Swift 5*

### Output

```
Set user: nil
Set user: Optional(Philipp)
new name: nil
new name: Optional(Philipp)
Set user: Optional(Anna)
new name: Optional(Tom)
```

Ideally I'd like only to listen to `self.$user.sink` for when the object is set **AND** for when the content of the object changes. 
I've played around with `self.objectWillChange.send()` when setting the username, but I'm not able to trigger the outer publisher.

I'm looking for a way to get rid of

```swift
guard let user = user else { return }
self.userContentCancel = user.$name.sink { _ in
    print("new name: \(String(describing: self.user))")
}
```

in my implementation and just drive everything from the same `self.$user.sink { (user) in` implementation.

Comment: If possible, your user should be a struct and therefore immutable. Then you would just have the outer subscriber since changing the name requires a new instance of `User`. Make it confirm to `Identifiable` with the same underlying unique identifier if required so that you know that is the same user with a different name. You can't fire the `AccountService` publisher from within `User` because the user object doesn't know that it is referenced by the account service

Comment: @Paulw11 That is a good idea. I will play around. The problem is that the user object can be updated in by change listener that monitors the user object. And that is implemented inside the user it self, so it does not pollute the rest of the code. So `changeUserName()` is called from inside on an update.

Comment: If you adopt immutability then `changeUserName()` goes away. You could have a function on your struct `user(withNewName:String)` that returns a new instance of the user with other properties the same but a new name.  It is hard to say exactly what you should do because I don't know exactly what you are trying to achieve.  You could use [`combineLatest`](https://heckj.github.io/swiftui-notes/#reference-combinelatest) to merge the two publishers into one.

Comment: combining them into one seems like a good idea. I can probably hide that away nicely too. thanks @Paulw11 for your thoughts. I'll update this here, once I found a elegant solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. You can simply use Combine's [flatMap](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/merge/flatmap(maxpublishers:_:)-2z9wm) operator:

> Transforms all elements from an upstream publisher into a new publisher up to a maximum number of publishers you specify.

My working example:

```swift
import Foundation
import Combine

class User: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    var debugDescription: String {
        return self.name
    }
}

class AccountService {
    @Published var user: User? = nil
    var userCancel: AnyCancellable?
    
    init() {
        self.userCancel = self.$user
            .filter { $0 != nil }
            .flatMap { $0!.$name }
            .sink(receiveValue: { name in
                print(name)
            })
    }

    func setUseru(user: User) {
        self.user = user
    }

    func changeUserName(name: String) {
        self.user?.name = name
    }
}

let x = AccountService()
x.setUseru(user: User(name: "Philipp"))
x.changeUserName(name: "Tom")
x.setUseru(user: User(name: "Anna"))
```

The program's output will be:

```
Philipp
Tom
Anna
```

Comment: I believe you could replace the filter and flatMap with a single call to compactMap, e.g.  .compactMap { $0?.name }

Comment: No, that's unfortunately not the same as in my example. Output with `compactMap` would be only "Philipp, Anna", missing out "Tom". That's because `compactMap` removes nil results, but `flatMap` returns a new publisher.